# Why does getline reads only the first stroke?

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

My program should read commands and do them with one number. It should +, -, /, * the number, but it reads only the first stroke.

```
    ifstream fin("file.txt");
    string line;
    while(getline(fin,line))
    {
        if(line[0] == '+')
        {
            for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                n += line[i];
            }
            ss << n;
            double p = 0.0;
            ss >> p;
            res += p;
        }
        n = "";
        if(line[0] == '-')
        {
            for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                n += line[i];
            }
            ss << n;
            double m = 0.0;
            ss >> m;
            res -= m;
        }
        n = "";
        if(line[0] == '*')
        {
            for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                n += line[i];
            }
            ss << n;
            double di = 0.0;
            ss >> di;
            res *= di;
        }
        n = "";
        if(line[0] == '/')
        {
            for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                n += line[i];
            }
            ss << n;
            double mu = 0.0;
            ss >> mu;
            res /= mu;
        }
        n = "";
    }
```

file example:

```
+1
-2
*5
```

output:

```
1
```

Expected output is -5, but it outputs 1.
Why is it happening and what should I do?
ss is a stringstream, n is a string, res is a double, strokes[] are strings.

Comment: Your [mre] is not reproducible. What is `ss`? `n`? `res`? Why are you looping after identifying the operation?

Comment: Include the relevant code. **Read** the link I posted.

Comment: I am able to make a few more assumptions, enough to say you've over-complicated your solution significantly, but not quite enough to provide an actual answer. This is why learning to ask questions properly is so important. It avoids this worthless back and forth and gets straight to the issue. I'd also recommend reading [ask] again. I will say that for a first effort, is pretty good.

Comment: `p = n;` would be  a much simpler approach. And even simpler: `res += n;`, with no intermediate variable and no forced conversions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You found out alread by yourself. You must either clear the `std::istringstream` or define a new one, even with the same name. So you coud write

```
    ss.clear(); // Clear EOF bit
    ss.str(std::string()); // Clear buffer
```

before the next insertion operation, or, you simply define a new variable every time by writing:

```
    std::stringstream ss{};
    ss << n;
```

I also modified your code to a minimum reproducable example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string line{};
    std::stringstream ss{};
    std::string n{};
    double res{};

    std::ifstream fin("file.txt");

    while (std::getline(fin, line))
    {
        if (line[0] == '+')
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < line.length(); i++)
            {
                n += line[i];
            }
            ss << n;
            double p = 0.0;
            ss >> p;
            res += p;
        }
        n = "";
        if (line[0] == '-')
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < line.length(); i++)
            {
                n += line[i];
            }
            ss.clear(); // Clear EOF bit
            ss.str(std::string()); // Clear buffer
            ss << n;
            double m = 0.0;
            ss >> m;
            res -= m;
        }
        n = "";
        if (line[0] == '*')
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < line.length(); i++)
            {
                n += line[i];
            }
            ss.clear(); // Clear EOF bit
            ss.str(std::string()); // Clear buffer
            ss << n;
            double di = 0.0;
            ss >> di;
            res *= di;
        }
        n = "";
        if (line[0] == '/')
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < line.length(); i++)
            {
                n += line[i];
            }
            ss.clear(); // Clear EOF bit
            ss.str(std::string()); // Clear buffer
            ss << n;
            double mu = 0.0;
            ss >> mu;
            res /= mu;
        }
        n = "";
    }
    std::cout << res;
    return 0;
}
```

And I added a code with a little bit more modern C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    
    if (std::ifstream ifs{ "file.txt" }; ifs) {

        double result{};
        for (std::string line{}; std::getline(ifs, line); ) {

            char calculationOperator{};
            double number{};

            std::istringstream iss{ line };
            if (iss >> calculationOperator >> number) {

                switch (calculationOperator) {
                case '+':
                    result += number;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    result -= number;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    result *= number;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    result /= number;
                    break;
                default:
                    std::cerr << "\n\nError: invalid mathematical operator '" << calculationOperator << "' found\n\n";
                }
            }
            else
                std::cerr << "\n\nError: Wronng input in line: " << line << "\n\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n\nResult:  " << result << "\n\n";
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "\n\nError: Could not open 'file.txt'\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```